# rails singular_collection_ids validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, collections

I have a form in rails app that allows to update **singular_collection_ids** attribute (relation type is **has_many through**). And I also need to validate it before update.

The problem that is validation requires previous value of object, but there is no method **singular_collection_ids_was** to provide this value. Also **singular_collection_ids** method works directly with join table with no temporary values, so

```
self.class.find(id).singular_collection_ids
```

inside validation did not help.

Is there any way to get previous value in stage of validation?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this ? maybe there's an other way than using `singular_collection_ids`.

Comment: In my case for example - I have two models: **Player** and **Achievement** they are linked to each other through model **JoinModel**. So in both edit forms of players and achievements I have checkboxes of linked models - so I can stick array of players to ahievement or array of achievements to a player. So it looks like: `Player.find(blabla).achievement_ids = [2,3,4]`. And by app logic I should check previous data of this field (achievement_ids or player_ids)

Comment: The only way I solve my problem at this moment is overriding **singular_collection_ids=** method and adding instance variable to store previous value.

Comment: I guess your validation is to prevent achievements / players to be removed from the list ?

Comment: How did you know? Yes I want to prevent removing some 'joins'. I've already tried **before_remove** parameter for **has_many** instruction, but do not know how to turn it in validation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works (and it's definitely quirky) but you could try this :

```
 class Player

   has_many :join_models, before_remove: :prevent_achievement_removal

   def prevent_achievement_removal( join_model )
     errors.add( :base, "Cannot remove an achievement this way !" )
     raise ::ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
   end

 end
```

according to [the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), if the callback raises any error, the record is not removed. However, something does not really feel right about this... I'll try to think about a better solution.

Comment: In my case class looks like:
`class Player << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :join_models
    has_many :achievements, through: :join_models, before_remove :blabla

    def blabla
      # ...
    end`
But only adding of error :base and returning false won't do anything, and raising of exception will stop the program. So before remove is kinda additional event trigger, and how to use it like validation process I do not know

Comment: somehow **before_remove** event works not the same way with model's **before_update** etc (which are allow to add errors if necessary and make update action invalid).

Comment: There is also next text in rails guides in associations block: _You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model_ But I didn't got what they were meaning by this sentence.

Comment: they mean `has_many :through`as opposed to `has_and_belongs_to_many`, where you have no control over the join model. As to your problem, i'll try to think about another solution... I think you may workaround this using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :join_model, allow_destroy: false` but this needs further thinking.

Comment: Got one more idea, that also failed - using **validates_associated**. If I try something like **validates_associated :achievements** inside **Player** class, I can use validations and see their results while updating Player model (I can get error message like _Achievement is invalid_ but it is something at least). But if I try to to use **validates_associated :join_models** inside Player - It also will call their validations, but instead of form invalid message it will throw an exception o_0. Anyway if it even could work I do not know how to determine which action was performed on model.